# How to convert JSon data to excel format in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx

[image]I want show below jason data in Excel format in react, where 1 object price has  3 values and 2nd have only one price, show price for orange in one cell in  3 rows

```
let jsonData = [{color:'orange', price:[100,200, 300]}, {color:'red', price:[100]]
```

Comment: In these cases where you want a specific format, it would be loads more helpful to show the output you desire rather than just describing it.

Comment: added the image plz have a look

Comment: As far as I'm aware, CSV (the client side way of creating excel files) doesn't support merging cells. You could use some 3rd party tools for this, but of course that will involve some extra learning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to https://www.npmjs.com/package/pandas-js to solve the problem
Load your json file and there will be function named as toDataFrame() then from dataframe to excel.
Hope this will help you